# How to test contextDestroyed in IntelliJ Jetty Runner

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I am using Intellij Jetty runner. And I implemented ServletContextListener. But I can't find a way to stop Jetty runner gracefully so that contextDestroyed is invoked. The only way to stop Jetty Runner is to click the "stop" which doesn't seem to invoke contextDestroyed

Answer (score 0):

You might configure a stop port in your jetty runner.  In your run configuration that launches the jetty runner, add parameters similar to those in this command line:

```
java -jar jetty-runner.jar --stop-port 8181 --stop-key abc123
```

Then you need to send a stop command to that port from a separate process.  Look up the usage of the `--stop` parameter in conjunction with `--stop-port` and `--stop-key` on how you can launch another jetty instance that will issue the stop message to your process.

I use the `jetty-maven-plugin` with the appropriate stop port and stop key configured, then I invoke

```
mvn jetty:stop
```

The stop port and stop key are configured in my pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <stopKey>stop-${project.artifactId}</stopKey>
        <stopPort>${jetty.admin.stop-port}</stopPort>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```